# Прямое подключение к VPN без создания сети возможно?

Tags: сеть, vpn, openvpn, l2tp

Если самостоятельно реализовать протокол PPTP, возможно ли напрямую подключиться к VPN-серверу (порт 1793) и обмениваться с ним командами, не создавая виртуальную сеть?
Например, есть 10 разных VPN-серверов - программа подключается в 10 потоков одновременно ко всем этим VPN и скачивает через них какую-либо веб-страницу, при этом остальные приложения на компьютере работают по обычной сети без VPN.
Некий аналог прокси.
Возможно ли это?

Comment: Разумеется можно, если сами весь протокол реализуете и сами же будете HTTP запросы слать. Правда рекомендую взять какой нибудь готовый код и адаптировать его. pptp сложный протокол, реализация - тысячи строк кода. И кстати по TCP/1723 идет только управляющее соединение PPTP, данные идут по PPP через 47 IP протокол, так что готовьтесь работать с сырыми сокетами, самому формировать IP-пакеты. (Вот TCP - это 6 IP протокол, а вам нужен 47 (GRE))

Comment: @Mike, значит разобраться в работе протокола PPTP и реализовать его довольно сложно? А, что можете сказать об OpenVPN, он более лёгок в реализации?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю он поддерживает разные протоколы, включая свои собственные. И PPTP и OpenVPN доступны в виде исходников, так что тут скорее вопрос адаптации. Часть реализующую устройства выбрасываете и заменяете на свою, часть работающую с сетью берете как есть